# How compare dynamic string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, filter, compare

I need to compare two strings in a custom filter I created in angular.

The problem is that the comparison is always `false`, and I checked the contents of both strings, length and type and they are equal. 
I have dealt with `localeCompare` , `==` `===` but they all return `false` in this case.

the strange thing is on the first part of the script, it works fine and both parts did the same.

this is my code:

```
.filter('search',function(){
    return function(items,arguments){//arguments -> object {columns,parameters}
        var i=0,j=0,filtered=[],nmbStr="",comp="";
        for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            nmbStr = (items[i][arguments.columns[0]]).toString();
            nmbStr = nmbStr.substr(0,arguments.parameters[0].length);
            switch(arguments.parameters.length){
                case 1:
                    if( nmbStr === arguments.parameters[0]) // 1st comparison here
                    filtered.push(items.slice(i,i+1)[0]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    comp = (items[i][arguments.columns[1]]);
                    comp = comp.substr(0,arguments.parameters[1].length);
                    comp = comp.toLowerCase();
                    if( nmbStr === arguments.parameters[0] && comp === arguments.parameters[1]){ // this is not working
                        filtered.push(items.slice(i,i+1)[0]);//crea un nuevo objeto a partir del array no una referencia
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
})
```

and I called like this:

```
$filter('search')(tempArray,{columns:['id','company_name'],parameters:['1052','in']});
```

please help me i don't not know what to do...

Comment: seems fine  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aukwvz9j/1/

Comment: Have you  tried putting some parentheses in `( nmbStr === arguments.parameters[0] && comp === arguments.parameters[1] )` so that the parser would clearly separate the operands, like this `( ( nmbStr === arguments.parameters[0] ) && ( comp === arguments.parameters[1] ) )`

Comment: thanks for the quickly answer. Finally works but i don't know why doesn't works at the begining.